# AVMutableComposition rotates recorded video

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video, avfoundation

I am building an iOS app using the AVFoundation Framework, objective-C and Xcode 7.1. What i am doing is get a recorded video, add a text layer and export. My problem is that the exported video is on landscape when i recorded on portrait! I 've been struggled for hours and can't solve it. I found similar questions but none of the answers helped me.
Here is my code:

```
  AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:self.videoURL options:nil];
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

AVMutableCompositionTrack* compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

CMTime insertTime = kCMTimeZero;
insertTime = CMTimeAdd(insertTime, compositionVideoTrack.timeRange.duration);

AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];


//  [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)
//                               ofTrack:clipVideoTrack
//                              atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVAssetTrack* audioAssetTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];

[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, clipVideoTrack.timeRange.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:insertTime error:nil];
[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration) ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:insertTime error:nil];

[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];


CGSize videoSize = [clipVideoTrack naturalSize];
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);

CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:32];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, 100)];
[subtitle1Text setString:self.titleField.text];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
subtitle1Text.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];
float startTime = 0.5f;
float duration = 4.0f;
overlayLayer.opacity = 0.0;
CABasicAnimation *myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[myAnimation setBeginTime: startTime];
[myAnimation setDuration: duration];
[myAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5]];
[myAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[myAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[overlayLayer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"myUniqueAnimationKey"];

AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool      videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];

AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);
AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];
videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];


NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* videoFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"textOverlayVideo-%@.mov",[NSDate date]];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:videoFileName];


fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];


AVAssetExportSession* exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];

exporter.outputURL = fileURL;
exporter.videoComposition = videoComp;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;


[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        switch (exporter.status)
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:

                NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                //[self syncFile];

                 imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
                [self send];

                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
                NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

}];}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = clipVideoTrack.preferredTransform;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution

```
 -(void)addTextOverlayToVideo
 {

// 2 - Create AVMutableComposition object. This object will hold your AVMutableCompositionTrack instances.
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];

// 3 - Video track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                                    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration)
                    ofTrack:[[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0]
                     atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

// 3.1 - Create AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *mainInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
mainInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, avAsset.duration);

// 3.2 - Create an AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction for the video track and fix the orientation.
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *videolayerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack = [[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
UIImageOrientation videoAssetOrientation_  = UIImageOrientationUp;
BOOL isVideoAssetPortrait_  = NO;
CGAffineTransform videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationRight;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationLeft;
    isVideoAssetPortrait_ = YES;
}
if (videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ =  UIImageOrientationUp;
}
if (videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0) {
    videoAssetOrientation_ = UIImageOrientationDown;
}
[videolayerInstruction setTransform:videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[videolayerInstruction setOpacity:0.0 atTime:avAsset.duration];

// 3.3 - Add instructions
mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:videolayerInstruction,nil];

AVMutableVideoComposition *mainCompositionInst = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];

CGSize naturalSize;
if(isVideoAssetPortrait_){
    naturalSize = CGSizeMake(videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width);
} else {
    naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize;
}

float renderWidth, renderHeight;
renderWidth = naturalSize.width;
renderHeight = naturalSize.height;
mainCompositionInst.renderSize = CGSizeMake(renderWidth, renderHeight);
mainCompositionInst.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:mainInstruction];
mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

CGSize videoSize =  naturalSize;
CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);

CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:22];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, 100)];
[subtitle1Text setString:self.titleField.text];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
subtitle1Text.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

CALayer *overlayLayer = [CALayer layer];
[overlayLayer addSublayer:subtitle1Text];
overlayLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[overlayLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:overlayLayer];
float startTime = 0.5f;
float duration = 4.0f;
overlayLayer.opacity = 0.0;
CABasicAnimation *myAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
[myAnimation setBeginTime: startTime];
[myAnimation setDuration: duration];
[myAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5]];
[myAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0]];
[myAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[overlayLayer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"myUniqueAnimationKey"];


 mainCompositionInst.renderSize = videoSize;
 mainCompositionInst.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
 mainCompositionInst.animationTool =    [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool      videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
//[self applyVideoEffectsToComposition:mainCompositionInst size:naturalSize];

// 4 - Get path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *myPathDocs =  [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"FinalVideo-%d.mov",arc4random() % 1000]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:myPathDocs];

// 5 - Create exporter
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition
                                                                  presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL=url;
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst;



[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        switch (exporter.status)
        {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:

                NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
                //[self syncFile];

                 imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                [self send];

                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
                NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

}];
```

}

Comment: I don't understand how you fixed it because I can't see how `videoAssetOrientation_ ` and `isVideoAssetPortrait_` are used. In any case, can you accept your answer?